# JQuery $_POST and $_FILES array are empty

Tags: jquery

I am trying to upload an image from inside a JQuery modal. The form is hidden in php and once a link is clicked the modal window appears, along with a very simple form, just a file upload field

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadprofileimage"    name="uploadprofileimage">
        <label for="image">Upload a picture of the item:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
        </form>
```

However when the upload button is clicked the form is serialized and sent. To try and resolve this issue I have post back to the page and when I dump $_POST and $_FILES the arrays are empty, where am I going wrong? I have done post before when I have posted variables to PHP, but for some reason I cannot post a form!

Below is my JQuery code, hope someone can help!, Thanks

```
$("[href='#avatar']").click(function() {
            $("#profile-upload").dialog({
                title: 'Add a profile image',
                width: 400,
                height: 200,

                buttons:[  

                { 
                text: 'Upload',
                click: function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var post = $("#uploadprofileimage").serialize();
                    $.post("profiles.php", post, function(data){
                        console.log(post);
                        console.log(data);


                    },'json');


                }


                },

                { text: 'Close', click: function() { $(this).dialog('close');}}



                ]


            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload files using AJAX.  You can however use one of many plugins that simulate AJAX action.  They do this by creating an `iframe` in the background and submitting the data that way.  Try searching for jQuery file upload plugins.

Comment: Great thanks for that Tim, think I will let PHP handle the file uploads then!